# how to backup mysql database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

Is it possible through the use of a batch file, I'm trying this code:

```
mysqldump --host=localhost --user=root --password=nitoryolai -R hospital >E:\wamp\etc\db-backup\hosp.sql
```

Then vb.net will execute the batch file through s.d.p.s("b.bat")
But it doesn't work, it only creates an empty .sql file.
Can you tell me what's wrong with the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to localize the problem. Try executing command without batch file. If it works try the batch itself outside of VB.
Also, try

```
s.d.p.s("call b.bat")
```